# Integrating Sql Server 2005 Databases into Team Foundation Server 2008

Tags: tfs

Is it Possible to integrate sql server databases into visual studio team foundation server 2008 as all possible circumstances like build making, version control,publishing etc....
and pls make sure that if we integrate this in to a team project combined both code and db in a single project and i would like know how it is possible....?

Comment: Please clarify and focus your question. It is very difficult to understand what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Red Gate SQL Source Control product. Thats what we use to version our database in TFS.